# python : collection in python saving duplicate data - why?

Tags: python, json

Hi i got a problem while writing a python programme, below is the code -

```
 import json as j
 import _collections
 x=[('Victor','Microsoft',7),('David','Facebook','5'),('Stephen','Google',8)]
 tab_d=['Name','Company','Exp']
 db_data=[]
 db_single={}
 for i,data in enumerate(x):
     db_single[tab_d[0]] = data[0]
     db_single[tab_d[1]] = data[1]
     db_single[tab_d[2]] = data[2]
     db_data.append(db_single)
 j=j.dumps(db_data)
 file = open('firstjson.js', 'w')
 file.write(j)
```

The o/p shows me `[{"Name": "Stephen", "Company": "Google", "Exp": 8}, {"Name": "Stephen", "Company": "Google", "Exp": 8}, {"Name": "Stephen", "Company": "Google", "Exp": 8}]` i.e. Stephen is adding three times instead of adding all members. Can some one plls suggest me what wrong i am doing?

Comment: You're appending the same object to `db_data` over and over.

Comment: it cant be, for each and every loop, the content in data will vary, is n't it?

Comment: Doesn't matter. You're still appending the same object to `db_data` every time.

Comment: Because your original code never sets `db_single` to something new, it is always the same object created before the call to enumerate. This means db_data has 3 references to the exact same object, and each time you modify that object's contents, those references to it will naturally reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only creating *one* object `db_sigle` which gets appended every time and only the values keep changing.

You have to make this change:

```
 ...
 for i,data in enumerate(x):
     db_single={}
     db_single[tab_d[0]] = data[0]
 ...
```

Otherwise your referencing and changing the same object

Comment: Great,Thank you for the help, its working as i want now :)

Comment: b/w, what is the difference? why should i empty the dict in loop instead of begining of programme?

Comment: This is a well-known and common confusion regarding passing arguments by value vs by reference. See for example [this article](https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php)

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, thanks!